# Find out the total system installation size

Tags: apt, system-installation, package-management

An Ubuntu installation may vary hugely in size, depending on the installed packages. Is there any quick way to check how mutch disk the current installation uses.

I want to know, because I plan to build a new PC, with a smaller and fast SSD for `/` and a large mechanical drive for `/home` (I have need for a large home directory), to decresase boot time. To solve this problem I would like to know the size of my current installation, so I know how large the system file system needs to be for my use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work on any GNU/Linux system:

```
(sudo du -b -s $(ls | grep -v 'home\|media\|mnt\|proc\|sys\|run') ) | awk -M '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

I find that my current installation is 9 892 901 210 bytes, or approximately 10 GB.

Comment: This seems to depend on which `awk` you are using. In Ubuntu minimal you get `awk: not an option: -M`

Comment: Same issue in Xubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 3):

Try `df -h`.

It will show information in the form

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
```

Comment: This works if the current installation already uses separate filesystems. Would it otherwise be sufficient to sum `/bin` `/boot` `/etc` `/lib`  `/lib64` `/opt` `/usr` `/var`, and remember the UEFI partition of 512 MB.

Comment: Seems to be sufficient.

Comment: @user877329 - give a good amount of extra room in /boot, otherwise a few kernel updates will fill it and `apt` will break.

Comment: @ravery, I know, learned the hard way. I do not plan to use a separate boot partition